# box-sizing: border-box - Size not maintained if border is changed afterwards

Tags: css, firefox-addon-webextensions, border-box

I'm stuck with a problem using `box-sizing: border-box`: I've 3 `div` sized with `min-height: 24px` I'd like to maintain the height whatever it is when adding horizontal borders.

The problem is that if horizontal borders are added *after* the content height has been computed once, then the content height isn't changed, and the `div` grows by the value of the borders.

In my case, borders are added by CSS itself when the element is hovered.

[image]
<sub>Height of first `div` increases when hovered, increasing the height of the whole page</sub> ↑

In case this is relevant:

- The page is actually used as a popup in a [Firefox webextension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/WebExtensions).
- I'm using two style sheets, one which I cannot modify (`extension.css`) and one I use to extent and overwrite the first one (`page-small.css`).
- One style is applied to each of the `div` to overwrite `height: 24px` in the protected CSS by `min-height: 24px;` to allow for the elements to grow with the content.

How can I manage this growth without having the external size changing when the element is hovered?

```css
.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.addl-text {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.start {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#col-1 {
  max-width: 300px;
}
#pli-1,
#pli-2,
#pli-3 {
  height: unset;    /* Want to cancel effect of...        */
  min-height: 24px; /* ...'height: 24px' in extension.css */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/4f41a072c0ca/browser/components/extensions/extension.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="page-small.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="col-1" class="panel-section">
    <fieldset class="panel-section-list">
      <legend>Checkboxes</legend>
      <div id="pli-1" class="panel-list-item">
        <div class="start">
          <input id="c11" type="checkbox">
          <label class="no-wrap" for="c11">Test</label>
          <label class="addl-text" for="c11">Voluptate nisi expe tendis eiusmod firmissimum de cillum nam eiusmod firmis simum expetendis, ipsum offendit.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-section-separator"></div>
      <div id="pli-3" class="panel-list-item">
        <input id="c12" type="checkbox">
        <label class="no-wrap" for="c12">Test</label>
      </div>
      <div id="pli-2" class="panel-list-item">
        <input id="c13" type="checkbox">
        <label class="no-wrap" for="c13">Test</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve what you want by simply add a hidden border.

Add hidden border (white colored) to items, so that height won't increase. like in the snippet.

```
.panel-list-item:not(.disabled) {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

You may want to tweak other styles too fix issues.

```css
.panel-list-item:not(.disabled) {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.addl-text {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.start {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#col-1 {
  max-width: 300px;
}
#pli-1,
#pli-2,
#pli-3 {
  height: unset;    /* Want to cancel effect of...        */
  min-height: 24px; /* ...'height: 24px' in extension.css */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/4f41a072c0ca/browser/components/extensions/extension.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="page-small.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="col-1" class="panel-section">
    <fieldset class="panel-section-list">
      <legend>Checkboxes</legend>
      <div id="pli-1" class="panel-list-item">
        <div class="start">
          <input id="c11" type="checkbox">
          <label class="no-wrap" for="c11">Test</label>
          <label class="addl-text" for="c11">Voluptate nisi expe tendis eiusmod firmissimum de cillum nam eiusmod firmis simum expetendis, ipsum offendit.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-section-separator"></div>
      <div id="pli-3" class="panel-list-item">
        <input id="c12" type="checkbox">
        <label class="no-wrap" for="c12">Test</label>
      </div>
      <div id="pli-2" class="panel-list-item">
        <input id="c13" type="checkbox">
        <label class="no-wrap" for="c13">Test</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer to my question, but it also looks like a bypass. Is `box-sizing` behavior actually buggy in Firefox (49)?

Comment: No. `box-sizing` is not buggy in any latest browsers, I think. Your issue is an expected behavior. When you add border on a div which don't have any border the height will increase to contain that border. To remove that flickering you have to go this way or other. That's not a bypass. :). Or you can add box-shadow too to get the effect. If the answer is helpful please mark it as accepted to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with the box-sizing property, borders are not included in the calculation for either border-box or content-box; the size of your element will always be increased by the size of the border you apply.

**If you do not want your element to increase in size, then don't add a border.**

If you want a border *effect*, without the physical properties of a border, then I would suggest using box-shadow instead. It's trivial to create a border effect with box-shadow, and it will not increase the size of the element it is applied to.

For example:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #333;
```

instead of:

```
border: 1px solid #333;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*borders are not included in the calculation*", as `box-sizing: border-box` is actually defined as "The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border" ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)).

Comment: This was bothering me too. The description of what it does is kind of misleading. If your element doesn't have an explicit height it will change the height of the element because there is no height to calculate. What it's really saying is we will factor in the border to the height you give us, if you don't supply a height we won't calculate anything.